# Creating a multi-bar plot in MatplotLib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Given a simple pd.Dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
                                                      workflow  blocked_14  blocked_7  blocked_5  blocked_2  blocked_1
au_in_service_order_response      au_in_service_order_response       12.00      11.76      15.38       25.0        0.0
au_in_cats_sync_billing_period  au_in_cats_sync_billing_period        3.33       0.00       0.00        0.0        0.0
au_in_MeterDataNotification        au_in_MeterDataNotification        8.70       0.00       0.00        0.0        0.0
```

I want to create a bar-chart that shows the `blocked_*` columns as the x-axis.

Since `df.plot(x='workflow', kind='bar')` obviously puts the `workflows` on the x-axis, I tried `ax = blocked_df.plot(x=['blocked_14','blocked_7',...], kind='bar')` but this gives me

> ValueError: x must be a label or position

How would I create 5 y-Values and have each bar show the according value of the workflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `pandas` interprets the x as the index and y as the values you want to plot, you'll need to transpose your dataframe first.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = df.set_index('workflow').T.plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

But that doesn't look too good does it? Let's ensure all of the labels fit on the `Axes` and move the legend outside of the plot so it doesn't obscure the data.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 6), layout='constrained')
ax = df.set_index('workflow').T.plot.bar(legend=False, ax=ax)
ax.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, .8))
plt.show()
```

[image]